# Attach breakpoints bind, Run does not?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging, next.js

I have the following two configs defined in my launch.json in vscode:

```
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "pnpm run dev",
    
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: attach",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9229
    },
```

This is the dev command:     `"dev": "NODE_ENV=development NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192 --inspect' cross-env next dev"`

In vscode if I run 'Next.js: debug server-side' the breakpoints in the backend don't bind.

If I run `pnpm run dev` then use 'Next.js: attach' vscode breakpoints start to bind.

Not sure what the difference is causing this?